# Problems with installation libgd3:i386 on ubuntu container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc

I have a standard ubuntu container (14.04 LTS), created by:

```
lxc-create -B btrfs -t ubuntu -n xxx
```

On this container:

libgd3 was installed correctly:

```
LANG=EN_GB apt-get install -f libgd3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgd3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but, I need libgd3:i386, for some 32 bit applications, and I can't install it:

```
LANG=EN_GB apt-get install -f libgd3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgd3
```

Any ideas, sugestions?

ATM I copied all libraries I need from host (there was no problem with installation libgd3:i386 on the host), and after update */etc/ld.so.conf.d/i686-linux-gnu.conf* and *ldconfig*, my application has started.

But this is very ugly solution, and I don't like it. I have a lot of containers to create this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found.

In short:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

[Full answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551840/unable-to-locate-package-libc6-dbgi386-in-docker)